# Catching NodeJS errors using a discord.js command handler

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a **Discord bot**, but have some problems **catching the errors** that my bot sends.
I'm using a custom **command handler**, that is working pretty well.

```js
Fs.readFile(`./database/prefixes/prefixes.json`, "utf8", (err: Error, data): void => {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    const prefix: string = data[message.author.id] == undefined ? "ma!" : data[message.author.id];

    const msg: string = message.content;
    const args: string[] = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
    const cmd: string = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!msg.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return checkCustomCommands();
    }

    let ops: {} = {
        queue: queue
    }

    try {
        require(checkFolders(cmd)).run(Client, message, args, ops); // maybe catching just there?
        Logger.log(`${message.author.tag} just used the ${cmd} power in ${message.guild.name}.`);
    } catch (err) {
        Logger.log(`The command ${message.author.tag} tried to call in ${message.guild.name} doesen't seem to exist.`);
    }

});

function checkCustomCommands() {
    let content = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync('./database/commands/commands.json', 'utf8'));

    try {
        if (content[message.guild.id][message.content] == undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            message.channel.send(content[message.guild.id][message.content]);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return;
    }
}

function checkFolders(command) {
    let folders = ["moderation", "fun", "music", "info", "game"];
    var files: string[];
    var finalPath: string;

    folders.forEach(folder => {
        files = Fs.readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`);

        files.forEach(file => {
            if (file.split(".")[0] == command) {
                return finalPath = `./../commands/${folder}/${file.split(".")[0]}.js`;
            }
        });
    });

    return finalPath;
}
```

But sometimes, my bot sends **various errors** that I can't catch into the commands files, resulting in my bot being **shutdown**. Is there any way to **prevent** that inside the command handler, or anything I can do to **catch these errors**?

Thanks a lot, I can provide more code if needed, even though the biggest chunk of the command handler is just there ^

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly... your bot is crashing and it's not showing any error message so you don't know why it is crashing?

Comment: Not exactly ; I know why my bot is crashing, however, I want it to prevent crashing inside the command handler

Comment: I recommend fixing the reason why your bot is crashing. Otherwise, if you know which part of your code is throwing errors, you can just put a try-catch block around it. You might also want to look into [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) or another similar package that can restart your app after a crash.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite late to this, but I feel like I should answer my own question, now that I'm able to do so haha

The main way to catch these errors is by listening to the `unhandledRejection` event, via Node `process`.

Here's how I did it:

```
async function handleRejections() {
    process.on("unhandledRejection", (error: Error) => {
        const errorEmbed: Discord.MessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription("<:no:835565213322575963> An error has been detected... \n" + `\`\`\`${error.stack}\`\`\``)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor("DARK_RED")

        logError(client, errorEmbed);
    });
}
```

Be sure to call the function at the very beginning of the project code, even before the bot starts.

I personally log these errors into a Discord channel, on my server, so that I can check them easily. That's it! Hope that helps. Keep on coding :D